# Autolinking is not set up in `settings.gradle`: expo modules won't be autolinked

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, autolink

I am designing a React Native application and I would like to create an Apk to test the app.
But when I click on "Sync project with Gradle Files" on Android Studio, I get the following error:

```
Autolinking is not set up in `settings.gradle`: expo modules won't be autolinked.
```

I don't understand what the problem is or rather how to configure Autolinking.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to `settings.gradle` ([Reference](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/))

```
apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
useExpoModules()
```